# Pivot Table doesn't seem to be correct way to fix? Add rows based on data type and return value?

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling with either using a pivot table or writing a query that will get the database in Columns A-E to format as Columns G-I. As you can imagine, I'm working with hundreds of thousands lines of data; however, the Column Helpers in A-E will also be set to what currently exists.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oP9N9_dAtdfhM2W0JrpSBsDgwHw4JTBpNsQAH1zXB0M/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with two options for you. However, here I will only post the option that matches your exact request. In B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"ID","Type","Value";QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")&"|"&Sheet1!B1:E1&"|"&FILTER(Sheet1!B2:E,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")),"|"),"Select * Where Col3 Is Not Null")})`

This formula creates the three headers (which you can change as you like), and then does the following:

1.) concatenate all non-blank entries in A2:A, a pipe symbol, each header in B1:E1, another pipe symbol and each element of the B2:E grid where A2:A is not blank. This will form a grid of results the same size as B2:E where A2:A is not blank, each in the format X|Y|Z.

2.) this grid of results is `FLATTEN`ed into one column.

3.) that column of results is split into three columns at the pipe symbols.

4.) `QUERY` weeds out any entries where the third column ("Value") is null.